# How to query in laravel 4.2 with 'as and expressions'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to convert this SQL query to Laravel Query

```
$query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * 
cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - 
radians('$lon') ) + 
sin( radians('$lat') ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM yourtable HAVING distance < '$miles' ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0, 5";
```

Heres what I did but I guess I really don't have any idea about this.

```
$stores = DB::table('stores')
->select( DB::raw( 'stores.*, ( ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * 
cos( radians( stores.latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( stores.longitude ) - 
radians('.$lon.') ) + 
sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * 
sin( radians( stores.latitude ) ) ) ) 
as distance' ) )
    ->orderBy('distance')->where('domain',$domain->appEnv)->get();
```

Comment: And where is your attempt?

Comment: there I put it I dont know if it even helps?

Comment: I don't understand the end goal here. If you don't care about accuracy you could just do a bounding box and it'll be less processing per query (assuming you'd doing this a lot). The problem I have even with your attempt is I don't understand what you want.